# Can't create keystore using keytool

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, ssl, encryption

I ran the following command to create a keystore in command line according to [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Quick_Start)

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

and I get the following error:

```
keytool error (likely untranslated): java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused:connect
```

Can anyone tell me what's causing this error and what I can do to create a keystore? 
Thank you

Comment: Just a guess: you did not install the keystore correctly (e.g. ran command in wrong path) and connections are refused because there is no keystore now.

Comment: @zapl keytool.exe is part of the jdk. I ran this command from bin folder(where this command resides) of my jdk and still got same error. Reinstalling my jdk might help?

Comment: I can't think why keytool would make any network connections. That's very weird. The command syntax you used is correct. Perhaps try specifying the name of the keystore file you want to modify; for a simple test keep the file in the same directory: `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore test.jks`

Comment: I recently heard about a free utility called [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) that can do all of your dirty work when using Java Keystores. (I've always hated using JKS after years of ease using plain-old PEM-encoded files with OpenSSL.)

Comment: Is that message _exactly_ what was written? If so, it's very strange as it is missing a `.` between `net` and `Connection`. And keytool shouldn't need to connect to the rest of the world either. What's your classpath?

Comment: @DonalFellows I missed the dot between net and connection. This is my classpath variable .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%ANT_HOME%\lib;%GRADLE_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping for the expanded version, so we could check if there were any non-local elements in it. (Probably aren't any, but it would've been an explanation.)